# node js azure error accessing routes

Tags: node.js, azure

I have a node js application that works fine in my localhost and in AWS. I deployed it to Azure with the following web.config file in the root of the directory:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="iisnode" path="index.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
        </handlers>
         <iisnode nodeProcessCountPerApplication="4" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

In addition, I have a file iisnode.yml, also at the root of directory, with the line:

`nodeProcessCountPerApplication: 4`

The root directory contains a file `index.js` which is the entry point to the application, and it is configured to run an express app on port `process.env.PORT || 1337`. In package.json, the start command is `node index.js`.

The application gets deployed, but for every route I try to run I see the following error:

`The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.`

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add the rewrite mode in the `web.config` file, beside the `handlers` tag under `system.webServer` tag:

```
          <rewrite>
               <rules>
                    <rule name="DynamicContent">
                         <conditions>
                              <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
                         </conditions>
                         <action type="Rewrite" url="index.js"/>
                    </rule>
               </rules>
          </rewrite>
```

Any update, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: The above solution actually stops my Azure deployed app from running.